# SQL duration time calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have a table of historic bus positions at a given time, recorded once per second. The schema looks like this:

```
BusID        int         not null,
BreadcrumbID int         not null identity (1, 1),
BusStopID    int         null,
Timestamp    datetime    not null
```

I want to generate a bus stop schedule based on historic trips. A bus is "at a stop" if its `BusStopID` corresponds to the stop, and is not "at a stop" if the `BusStopID` is null.

I need to generate the average times the bus is at each stop. So basically, I need to do the following:

- Identify the times that a bus is at a stop -- a simple `where` clause does the trick
- Identify the average times the bus is at a stop. For my purposes, I'm defining a discrete "stop time" as a window of plus/minus 10 minutes; if a bus stops one day from 10:04 - 10:08, another day at 10:06 - 10:08, and a third day at 10:14 - 10:18, those would be the same stop, but if it stops at 10:45 - 10:48, that would be a different stop occurrence.
- Filter out "noise" -- i.e. stops times that only happened a few times but never again

I'm completely at a loss as to how to accomplish the second and third bullet. Please help!

Comment: Is `BusID` really supposed to increment for all timestamps? Also, since `Timestamp` is actually a data type in SQL, I would advise against using it as a column name, but I understand that you picked a name that makes sense (unlike the name of the data type itself).

Comment: Whoops, I made a mistake when typing up the schema in StackOverflow. You're correct, the breadcrumb ID increments and the BusID is a FK.

Comment: Interesting question, vastly trickier than it appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a number of occasions I've done something similar.  Essentially, grouping based on separations within a complex ordering.  The basics of the approach I use, with regards to this problem, are as follows:

1. Build a table of all time ranges of interest.
2. Find the starting time for each group of time ranges of interest.
3. Find the ending time for each group of time ranges of interest.
4. Join the starting and ending times to the list of time ranges, and group.

Or, in more detail: (each of these steps could be a part of one big CTE, but I've broken it down into temp tables for ease of reading...)

Step 1: Find the list of all time ranges of interest (I used a method similar to the one linked to by @Brad).  *NOTE: as @Manfred Sorg pointed out, this assumes there are no "missing seconds" in a bus's data.  If there is a break in the timestamps, this code will interpret the single range as two (or more) distinct ranges.*

```
;with stopSeconds as (
  select BusID, BusStopID, TimeStamp,
         [date] = cast(datediff(dd,0,TimeStamp) as datetime),
         [grp] = dateadd(ss, -row_number() over(partition by BusID order by TimeStamp), TimeStamp)
  from #test
  where BusStopID is not null
)
select BusID, BusStopID, date,
       [sTime] = dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,date,min(TimeStamp)), 0),
       [eTime] = dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,date,max(TimeStamp)), 0),
       [secondsOfStop] = datediff(ss, min(TimeStamp), max(Timestamp)),
       [sOrd] = row_number() over(partition by BusID, BusStopID order by datediff(ss,date,min(TimeStamp))),
       [eOrd] = row_number() over(partition by BusID, BusStopID order by datediff(ss,date,max(TimeStamp)))
into #ranges
from stopSeconds
group by BusID, BusStopID, date, grp
```

Step 2: Find the earliest time for each stop

```
select this.BusID, this.BusStopID, this.sTime minSTime,
       [stopOrder] = row_number() over(partition by this.BusID, this.BusStopID order by this.sTime)
into #starts
from #ranges this
  left join #ranges prev on this.BusID = prev.BusID
                        and this.BusStopID = prev.BusStopID
                        and this.sOrd = prev.sOrd+1
                        and this.sTime between dateadd(mi,-10,prev.sTime) and dateadd(mi,10,prev.sTime)
where prev.BusID is null
```

Step 3: Find the latest time for each stop

```
select this.BusID, this.BusStopID, this.eTime maxETime,
       [stopOrder] = row_number() over(partition by this.BusID, this.BusStopID order by this.eTime)
into #ends
from #ranges this
  left join #ranges next on this.BusID = next.BusID
                        and this.BusStopID = next.BusStopID
                        and this.eOrd = next.eOrd-1
                        and this.eTime between dateadd(mi,-10,next.eTime) and dateadd(mi,10,next.eTime)
where next.BusID is null
```

Step 4: Join everything together

```
select r.BusID, r.BusStopID,
       [avgLengthOfStop] = avg(datediff(ss,r.sTime,r.eTime)),
       [earliestStop] = min(r.sTime),
       [latestDepart] = max(r.eTime)
from #starts s
  join #ends e on s.BusID=e.BusID
              and s.BusStopID=e.BusStopID
              and s.stopOrder=e.stopOrder
  join #ranges r on r.BusID=s.BusID
                and r.BusStopID=s.BusStopID
                and r.sTime between s.minSTime and e.maxETime
                and r.eTime between s.minSTime and e.maxETime
group by r.BusID, r.BusStopID, s.stopOrder
having count(distinct r.date) > 1 --filters out the "noise"
```

Finally, to be complete, tidy up:

```
drop table #ends
drop table #starts
drop table #ranges
```

Comment: Great! One drawback: The grouping fails when the data isn't complete - when there's a second missing during a bus stop you'll get two bus stops counted.

Comment: With the final 'having', only produces one result. Without, produces duplicates and doesn't average times

Comment: @Manfred, you're correct... that was an assumption I made based on the dataset(s) I've used this on. If this is an invalid assumption, you can do something similar to the rest of the process (i.e. find matching starts and ends and group).

Comment: @chezy525 the one in my answer below. fun problem, eh?

Comment: huh, it seems you're correct.  The way I read the question, I think the single result is the right answer (all other results are single occurrences)...  Either way, there is a bug/unpredictable behavior with the above code for a bus that stops at different BusStops at the same time (obviously on different days), potentially creating duplicates or just outright wrong answers.  Don't know if this is an issue for the real dataset or not.

Comment: @smirkingman, I think I fixed the error that your test data exposed.  Note that since your dataset isn't incremented by the second, and there are gaps, the first step doesn't yield correct ranges.

Comment: @chezy525 That's precisely what makes this interesting. Take a bus that stops at stop 1, on random days, at 10:00, 10:11, 10:04, 10:07 and 10:15. This creates a single timetable entry, at 10:07:24 (the 5 stops were all within 10 minutes of one of the adjacent stops). However, if the 10:15 stop were at 10:22 (more than 10 minutes after 10:11), then it's 2 entries in the timetable, 10:05:30 and 10:22:00.

Comment: Of course, in my solution, one could write DATEPART(HOUR,TimeStamp) * 3600 + DATEPART(MINUTE,TimeStamp) * 60 + DATEPART(SECOND,TimeStamp) and compare against 600 instead of 10, but I thought is was less readable.

Answer (score 2):

**[This post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/)** I just saw may help you. (Sql Server Central)

Answer (score 0):

Fresh answer...

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @stopWindowMinutes INT
SET @stopWindowMinutes = 10

--
;
WITH    test_data
          AS ( SELECT   1 [BusStopId]
                       ,'2010-01-01 10:00:04' [Timestamp]
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-01 10:00:05'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-01 10:00:06'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-01 10:00:07'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-01 10:00:08'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:00:06'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:00:07'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:00:08'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:06'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:07'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:08'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:09'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:10'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:09'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:10'
               UNION SELECT   2,'2010-01-01 10:00:11'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:33:43'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:33:44'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:33:45'
               UNION SELECT   1,'2010-01-02 10:33:46'
             )
    SELECT DISTINCT
            [BusStopId]
           ,[AvgStop]
    FROM    ( SELECT    [a].[BusStopId]
                       ,( SELECT    MIN([b].[Timestamp])
                          FROM      [test_data] b
                          WHERE     [a].[BusStopId] = [b].[BusStopId]
                                    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [a].[Timestamp], 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [b].[Timestamp], 120)
                                    AND [b].[Timestamp] BETWEEN DATEADD(SECOND, -@stopWindowMinutes * 60,
                                                                        [a].[Timestamp])
                                                        AND     DATEADD(SECOND, @stopWindowMinutes * 60, [a].[Timestamp]) -- w/i X minutes

                        ) [MinStop]
                       ,( SELECT    MAX([b].[Timestamp])
                          FROM      [test_data] b
                          WHERE     [a].[BusStopId] = [b].[BusStopId]
                                    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [a].[Timestamp], 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [b].[Timestamp], 120)
                                    AND [b].[Timestamp] BETWEEN DATEADD(SECOND, -@stopWindowMinutes * 60,
                                                                        [a].[Timestamp])
                                                        AND     DATEADD(SECOND, @stopWindowMinutes * 60, [a].[Timestamp]) -- w/i X minutes

                        ) [MaxStop]
                       ,( SELECT    DATEADD(second,
                                            AVG(DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [b].[Timestamp], 120),
                                                         [b].[Timestamp])),
                                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN([b].[Timestamp]), 120))
                          FROM      [test_data] b
                          WHERE     [a].[BusStopId] = [b].[BusStopId]
                                    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [a].[Timestamp], 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [b].[Timestamp], 120)
                                    AND [b].[Timestamp] BETWEEN DATEADD(SECOND, -@stopWindowMinutes * 60,
                                                                        [a].[Timestamp])
                                                        AND     DATEADD(SECOND, @stopWindowMinutes * 60, [a].[Timestamp]) -- w/i X minutes

                        ) [AvgStop]
              FROM      [test_data] a
              WHERE     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Timestamp], 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Timestamp], 120)
              GROUP BY  [a].[BusStopId]
                       ,[a].[Timestamp]
            ) subset1
```

Comment: I think you misread -- the bus stops are identified by the BusStopID; the bus stop *times* are identified by the times.

Comment: @David, I updated my answer; see if this gets you going in the right direction. I haven't done a POC, but the idea *seems* solid.

Comment: @David, I added a POC to my answer. See if this is what you are wanting.

Comment: Try removing the day grouping: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Timestamp], 120)`

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, these kind of problems are easier to solve and maintain by breaking them into bite-sized pieces:

```
-- Split into Date and minutes-since-midnight
WITH observed(dates,arrival,busstop,bus) AS (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(CHAR(8), TimeStamp, 112),
        DATEPART(HOUR,TimeStamp) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE,TimeStamp),
        busstopid,
        busid
    FROM
        History
),
-- Identify times at stop subsequent to arrival at that stop
atstop(dates,stoptime,busstop,bus) AS (
    SELECT
        a.dates,
        a.arrival,
        a.busstop,
        a.bus
    FROM
        observed a 
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM
                observed b
            WHERE
                a.dates = b.dates AND
                a.busstop = b.busstop AND
                a.bus = b.bus AND
                a.arrival - b.arrival BETWEEN 1 AND 10
        )
),
-- Isolate actual arrivals at stops, excluding waiting at stops
dailyhalts(dates,arrival,busstop,bus) AS (
    SELECT
        a.dates,a.arrival,a.busstop,a.bus
    FROM
        observed a 
    WHERE
        arrival NOT IN (
            SELECT
                stoptime
            FROM 
                atstop b 
            WHERE
                a.dates = b.dates AND
                a.busstop = b.busstop AND
                a.bus = b.bus 
    )
),
-- Merge arrivals across all dates
timetable(busstop,bus,arrival) AS (
    SELECT
        a.busstop, a.bus, a.arrival
    FROM
        dailyhalts a 
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  
                *
            FROM
                dailyhalts h 
            WHERE
                a.busstop = h.busstop AND
                a.bus = h.bus AND
                a.arrival - h.arrival BETWEEN 1 AND 10
        )
    GROUP BY
        a.busstop, a.bus, a.arrival
)
-- Print timetable for a given day
SELECT
    a.busstop, a.bus, a.arrival, DATEADD(minute,AVG(b.arrival),'2010/01/01')
FROM
    timetable a INNER JOIN
    observed b ON
        a.busstop = b.busstop AND
        a.bus = b.bus AND
        b.arrival BETWEEN a.arrival AND a.arrival + 10
GROUP BY
    a.busstop, a.bus, a.arrival
```

Input:

```
ID  BusID   BusStopID   TimeStamp
1   1   1   2010-01-01 10:00:00.000
2   1   1   2010-01-01 10:01:00.000
3   1   1   2010-01-01 10:02:00.000
4   1   2   2010-01-01 11:00:00.000
5   1   3   2010-01-01 12:00:00.000
6   1   3   2010-01-01 12:01:00.000
7   1   3   2010-01-01 12:02:00.000
8   1   3   2010-01-01 12:03:00.000
9   1   1   2010-01-02 11:00:00.000
10  1   1   2010-01-02 11:03:00.000
11  1   1   2010-01-02 11:07:00.000
12  1   2   2010-01-02 12:00:00.000
13  1   3   2010-01-02 13:00:00.000
14  1   3   2010-01-02 13:01:00.000
15  1   1   2010-01-03 10:03:00.000
16  1   1   2010-01-03 10:05:00.000
```

Output:

```
busstop bus arrival (No column name)
1   1   600 2010-01-01 10:02:00.000
1   1   660 2010-01-01 11:03:00.000
2   1   660 2010-01-01 11:00:00.000
2   1   720 2010-01-01 12:00:00.000
3   1   720 2010-01-01 12:01:00.000
3   1   780 2010-01-01 13:00:00.000
```