# TSQL Time Series Pattern Data Mining

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Take a SQL table with the following 3 fields:

```
Id,TimeStamp,Item,UserId
```

I would like to determine the most common sequences of `Item` for a `UserId` in a session. A session would simply be defined by a threshold of time (i.e. if there are no entires for X minutes, any future entries would be grouped into a new session).

Ideally, the sequence of Items could have a sort of fuzzy grouping where one or two differences in the sequence could still be counted as the same and grouped together.

Anyone know how I might tackle this problem in SQL?

**Update:**
To clarify, lets pretend that the Items are grocery store isles. And I have a month of people visiting the grocery store.  The basic question is what isles are people using and it what order. Do they go isles `1,2,3` or `1,2,1,3,4` most frequently?

(Right now I am curious about paths of users on our sites, but you know, grocery store is more visual).

**Update 2:**
Here is a simple case:

```
CREATE Table #StoreActivity
(
    id int,
    CreationDate datetime ,
    Isle int,
    UserId int
)

Insert INTO #StoreActivity
Values
    (1, CAST('12-1-2011 03:10:01' AS Datetime), 1, 2222),
    (2, CAST('12-1-2011 03:10:07' AS Datetime), 1, 1111),
    (3, CAST('12-1-2011 03:10:12' AS Datetime), 2, 2222),
    (4, CAST('12-1-2011 04:10:01' AS Datetime), 1, 2222),
    (5, CAST('12-1-2011 04:10:23' AS Datetime), 2, 2222)

Select * from #StoreActivity
DROP Table #StoreActivity

/* So with the above data, we have 2 sequences if we declare a session or visit dead if there is no activity for a minute : `1,2` (With a count of 2), and `1` (with a count of 1)*/
```

Comment: if there is no "id" column on the table this is meaningless as the sequence of records in a table is not guaranteed.

Comment: @FilipDeVos: There is an id field, will update the question. But the sequence should based on the timestamp, not the id.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377028/sql-duration-time-calculation

Comment: even the trivial sample is fiendish... `create table demo(sessionId int, Item int) insert table values(1,1) insert table values(1,2) insert table values(2,1) insert table values(2,2)` it involves lots of self joining

Comment: @Kyle: could you please post a sample dataset and the desired output?

Comment: also @Kyle, simplify this ... I thing this would be easier to grok with a 2 column table

Comment: I wonder if it might be easier just to `concat` the whole session historys into strings of item ids like `,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,` then search for patterns in those.

Comment: @Sam: This seems like the most basic example. We are grouping on 'sessions'. Sessions are deterimined from time windows and userids. Then you are looking for sequences of items from those.

Comment: @Kyle: what does determine a complete path? In your example, there are `1`, `1,2`, `1,2,3`, etc.

Comment: @Quassnoi: The 4th Dimension, time ;-). So one way would be if there has been no entries for a UserId in X minutes, the path would be considered complete.

Comment: @Kyle: OK, seems to be more clear now. Will try to make the query. Does it, by any chance, has something to do with `SO` database so that I could test it on the dumped data? You can contact me privately if this is a secret yet :)

Comment: I'm building a log analysis app. Our web log data is soon to be all inserted into sql, and I happen to pass the userid to the logs as well. This isn't really a big requirement, but sometimes I start to wonder about how to solve a problem and get stuck in a loop :-) I've written stuff that does similar things before, groups log entires into "events" based on time, but that was all in languages like Python and Perl.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not going to spy on particular people are anything, it is just for abstract stuff like this, and to make it easy to find what is going on if users say they had issues. This will all be a circular buffer anyways.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Added a little example data of my Grocery store example.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY TimeStamp, Id) AS rn,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, Item ORDER BY TimeStamp, Id) AS rnd
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  *,
        rnd - rn AS sequence
FROM    q
```

The `sequence` column will be shared among all records in a sequence for a given `UserId`. You can group on it or do whatever you like.

Comment: That wasn't how I read the question. You are finding contiguous islands with the same `item` I thought the OP wanted to find patterns of `items`. So if `Item1,Item2,Item3` was a common sequence.

Comment: @Martin: from *one or two differences in the sequence could still be counted as the same and grouped together* I judge that the continuous series is what the @op wanted. My query doesn't do this, of course :)

Comment: @Martin's interpretation is correct. At least for a start, the one or two differences part of the request is probably just extra credit :-P Also, that last from should `FROM q` right?

Comment: @Kyle: of course, corrected. So if `1, 2, 3` would be a sequence, would then `1, 3, 5` be? In other words, should the sequences be serial or just ever-increasing?

Comment: @Quassnoi. I am looking for the paths of Items taken. For that reason you could say this was a grocery store and the items are isles. In a visit, did they go to isle 1, isle 3, and then back to isle 1, then checkout? So the sequences could really be anything.

Comment: @Kyle: is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487846/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-times-a-route-was-travelled-using-sql what you want?

Comment: @Quassnoi: That might just be it, going to take a little time make sure I understand it :-)

Comment: @Quassnoi: That looks right to me, with the additional challenge here that step does not exist and needs to be determined from by time groupings.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the old fashion Association Rule mining problem (but ordered which makes it easier), and if I have understood the question right, there is not one [EFFICIENT] SQL answer to this problem.

- If your problem involves maximum frequent route mining (e.g. a route 1,3,2 can be used in both routes 4,1,3,2 and 1,3,2,4), it would not be so easy to solve. I would suggest look at AR mining in SSAS data mining.
- If your problem does not involve maximum frequent route mining (e.g. 1,3,2 will be counted only if it the exact same route it used) then it is just a matter of group by and count.

Before you will be able to use any of the above solutions, you need to figure out your sessions which can be done using the following script:

```
WITH ts as
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        UserId, 
        CreationDate,
        Isle,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY CreationDate) AS rowNum
    FROM #StoreActivity a

)
SELECT t2.*, KeepSession = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(second,t1.CreationDate, t2.CreationDate) > 60 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   
INTO #tempStore
FROM ts as t1
LEFT JOIN ts as t2 ON t1.rowNum = t2.rowNum - 1 
WHERE t1.UserId = t2.UserId

SELECT *, id, UserId, 
SessionId = (SELECT count(*) FROM #tempStore where KeepSession = 0 and UserId = t.UserId and rowNum <= t.rowNum)
FROM #tempStore t
--where t. t.KeepSession = 0

DROP TABLE #tempStore
```

Result will be:

```
id          UserId      CreationDate            Isle        rowNum               KeepSession id          UserId      SessionId
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
3           2222        2011-12-01 03:10:12.000 2           2                    1           3           2222        0
4           2222        2011-12-01 04:10:01.000 1           3                    0           4           2222        1
5           2222        2011-12-01 04:10:23.000 2           4                    1           5           2222        1
6           2222        2011-12-01 04:10:24.000 3           5                    1           6           2222        1
7           2222        2011-12-01 04:12:23.000 3           6                    0           7           2222        2
8           2222        2011-12-01 04:12:24.000 3           7                    1           8           2222        2

(6 row(s) affected)
```

NOTE: Above solution can be optimized for performance. #tempStore can be removed.