# SQL Query to find a sequence of numbers in consequentive rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Say I have a SQL table and one of the columns has a sequence of numbers in rows that follow each other and I want to find if that sequence appears anywhere else in the table. Is it possible to create such a query?

Table A

1. 12.3
2. 14.5
3. 16.3

So I need to find where else those numbers are located in the same row sequence and to find those rows. Is this possible in SQL? I extracted the file from Excel as I couldn't figure a way to do it in excel.

Thanks gurus:)

Comment: Have a look at similar questions about finding a sequence in rows (postgres): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771141/querying-sequences-of-rows-in-sql and how to select rows depending on the value of the previous one http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/select-rows-depending-on-previous-row

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example? I don't know what you mean in `TableA`.

Comment: please select the appropriate tag, mysql and sql-server are different engines.

Answer (score 0):

concat is for `sql-server`

```
   1. concat these 3 number to a string
   2. concat next 3 numbers to a string
   3. compare these 2 strings
   4. if equel then you have it!

  do it in a loop
```